# Using bentoml, how to get the current bentos version?

Tags: bentoml

I'm using [BentoML framework](https://www.bentoml.com/) and want to get during runtime the build bentos version that is running. How to do it? Is there an api in `bentoml` package. See that I don't want the model hash, but the build that was used in the command `bentoml build -v <my_version>`.